# How to solve the problem "Unable to locate package libva1" when compile omxplayer in pi 3b+?

Tags: omxplayer

When i try to compile the Omxplayer in my raspberry 3b+, i just run the prepare script as the instructions from the README.md.
But I got the following error.
Can anybody explain this.
Thanks.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/omxp/omxplayer$ sh prepare-native-raspbian.sh 
Modifying for native build on Debian
Checking dpkg database for missing packages
.................
You are missing required packages.
Run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install  git-core libva1 libssl1.0-dev
pi@raspberrypi:~/omxp/omxplayer$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install  git-core libva1 libssl1.0-dev
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease                                                                     
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease                                                                  
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'git' instead of 'git-core'
E: Unable to locate package libva1
pi@raspberrypi:~/omxp/omxplayer$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git libva1 libssl1.0-dev
Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease                                                                 
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libva1
pi@raspberrypi:~/omxp/omxplayer$
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion include in the error message: Run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install  git-core libva1 libssl1.0-dev

Answer (score 6):

I responded on the [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/issues/731) you filed.

According to:

```
apt-cache search libva
```

there is no libva1 anymore but you can edit the script to replace it with `libva2`. This is sufficient to build OMXPlayer on Raspbian Buster.

Other things can go wrong with the build and in the ticket you had some additional problems which I addressed there, but these aren't related to libva*.